# Three20，TTLauncherItem set the image not in @"bundle://12.png"

Tags: iphone, three20, bundle, ttlauncheritem

if the image of TTLauncherItem is not from @"bundle://12.png" but as the following, it would not appear as a image.

```
    [pageArray addObject:[[[TTLauncherItem alloc] initWithTitle:[titleArray objectAtIndex:(j+i*pageCount)]
                                                                  image:@"/Users/alex/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.1/Applications/457F60DD-86EF-42E3-95F5-3BFC7C223987/Documents/magazine_covers/12.png"
                                                                    URL:@"tt://setUp" 
                                                              canDelete:NO] autorelease]];
```

Does this kind of init is not supported?

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure about a direct URL to an image on the file system. 
But I do the following for using an image within my project as a TTLauncherItem image:

```
NSString* imageName  = @"my-sweet-icon.png";
UIImage* thumbnail = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mySweetImage.png"]; 
[[TTURLCache sharedCache] storeImage:thumbnail forURL:imageName]; 
TTLauncherItem* item1 =  [[[TTLauncherItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                        image:imageName  
                                                        URL:@"tt://url" canDelete:NO] autorelease];
```

Comment: Where is imageName defined and how?

Answer (score 2):

iOS apps have no access to your local filesystem.  Use the `documents` keyword instead of the `bundle`.  A quick look at the code shows that it handles nested directories too.

```
@"documents://12.png"
```

Source: [Three20 source code](https://github.com/willbailey/three20/blob/master/src/Three20Network/Sources/TTURLCache.m)